# terraform env list return 'dev' environment but missing files [0.9.11]

Tags: terraform

we manage all resources on different folders using separated `terraform.tfstate` files, in case below we have 3 state files.

dev

- bastion
- webserver
- sql

I loop all folders and create new environment running: `terraform env new -state=.terraform/terraform.tfstate dev`

`terraform env list` return 2 environment (default,dev) but doesn't create the folder `terraform.state.d/` nor `.terraform/environment`

anyone familiar with that problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you're using local state? Are you sure `.terraform/terraform.tfstate` is really your state file? That file is only for terraform's internal use. If you can reproduce this with local state, you should file an issue.